# Distinction between a set and a class when generating sigma fields

Tags: measure-theory, elementary-set-theory

My question concerns a proof I believe may require thinking of a set as a class - I refer to this here as "viewing a set as a class". The problem concerns the generation of $\sigma$-fields by classes, a concept I am familiar with, but the proof I am having difficulty with concerns $\sigma$-fields being generated by sets - a concept I am not familiar with.

I am vaguely aware of some possible connections to axiomatic set theory regarding, for instance, classes not existing in the ZFC framework (only sets), but that classes are nonetheless used "for convenience" - see Jech, p5 (Set Theory, Third Millennium Edition). My basic understanding is all sets are classes but some classes are not sets (proper classes - not sure what these look like). Thus perhaps I have simply gotten used too much to using classes and have lost sight of the fact that only sets exist?

I suppose the question below is a particular example of a more general one: by virtue of a set always being a class, can any theorem, definition or logic involving classes be immediately applied to sets? The converse will not hold for proper classes I suppose - i.e results pertaining to sets do not carry over to classes unless the class is a set.

To illustrate what I am thinking I use the notation $\mathcal{P}_{\tau}(\Omega)=\{\{\omega\}:\omega\in\Omega\}$ to denote the finest partition of $\Omega$. I believe $\mathcal{P}_{\tau}(\Omega)$ to be a class, and furthermore since all sets are classes, by "viewing $\Omega$ as a class" we must surely have $\mathcal{P}_{\tau}(\Omega)=\Omega$? If $\Omega$ is indeed a class then presumably we can also view subsets of $\Omega$ as a subclass. For instance for any $B\subseteq\Omega$, and also when viewing $B$ as a class, we have $B=\{\{b\}:b\in B\}$. This implies we can write $B$ as $B=\left\{\{b\}\in\mathcal{P}_{\tau}(\Omega):b\in B\right\}$? Accordingly $\Omega$ and $B$ both viewed as a classes means $B$ can be written as a collection of all the singleton sets of $\mathcal{P}_{\tau}(\Omega)$ whose (single) elements are contained in $B$ - this also justifies writing $B$ as $B=\bigcup_{\{b\}\in\{B\cap \mathcal{P}_{\tau}(\Omega)\}}\{b\}$.

This all seems rather hard work and I strongly suspect unnecessary, but proof A uses these ideas.

**Claim:** If $\mathscr{F}=\sigma(\Omega)$ is a $\sigma$-field of subsets of $\Omega$ generated by $\Omega$ where $|\Omega|\leq\aleph_{0}$ then $\mathscr{F}=2^{\Omega}$

**Proof A:**

Since $2^{\Omega}$ is the class of all subsets of $\Omega$ then $A\in 2^{\Omega}$ holds for all $A\in\mathscr{F}$ which implies $\mathscr{F}\subseteq2^{\Omega}$ is true. Let $B\in 2^{\Omega}$. Noting $\Omega=\mathcal{P}_{\tau}(\Omega)$ (by viewing $\Omega$ as a class) and that $|B|\leq \aleph_{0}$ follows from $B\subseteq\Omega$, then $B$ can be written as $B=\bigcup_{\{\{b\}\in\{B\cap \mathcal{P}_{\tau}(\Omega)\}}\{b\}$ for a countable union of singleton sets  (by viewing $B$ as a class) which implies $B\subseteq\mathcal{P}_{\tau}(\Omega)$. Since $\mathcal{P}_{\tau}(\Omega)\subseteq\mathscr{F}$ holds from the properties of generated $\sigma$-fields then $B\subseteq\mathcal{P}_{\tau}(\Omega)$ implies it must be true that $\{b\}\in\mathscr{F}$ for each $\{b\}\in B$. Accordingly since $\sigma$-fields are closed under countable unions we must have $B\in\mathscr{F}$, which implies $2^{\Omega}\subseteq\mathscr{F}\hspace{10pt}\blacksquare$

The next proof does not directly use the above ideas and I suspect is the correct version.

**Proof B:**

Since $2^{\Omega}$ is the class of all subsets of $\Omega$ then $A\in 2^{\Omega}$ holds for all $A\in\mathscr{F}$ which implies $\mathscr{F}\subseteq2^{\Omega}$ is true. Let $B\in 2^{\Omega}$ and note $B\subseteq\Omega$ which implies $B$ can be written as $B=\bigcup_{b\in B}\{b\}$ for a countable union of elements of $\Omega$. Since $\Omega\subseteq\mathscr{F}$ holds from the properties of generated $\sigma$-fields then $B\subseteq\Omega$ implies it must be true that $\{b\}\in\mathscr{F}$ for each $b\in B$. Accordingly since $\sigma$-fields are closed under countable unions we must have $B\in\mathscr{F}$, which implies $2^{\Omega}\subseteq\mathscr{F}\hspace{10pt}\blacksquare$

Comment: "all sets are classes but some classes are not sets (proper classes)". CORRECT. The "universal" class $V \{ x \mid x=x \}$ is not a set. The same for the class of all *ordinals*.

Comment: In a nutshell, every "property" define a class but only a class that belong to another class is a sets.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA thank you for the reply. So if $A$ is given as a set and $p(a)\Longleftrightarrow a\in A$ is a property, then $\tilde{A}=\{\{a\}:p(a)=1\}$ is a class where $\tilde{A}=A$? And should I use proof B, or is proof A acceptable but perhaps not necessary?

Comment: and since $\Omega$ is a class (because it is a set) then do we have $\mathcal{P}_{\tau}(\Omega)=\Omega$?